# Name of multiple comparison post hoc of Kruskal-Wallis test in R agricolae package

Tags: kruskal-wallis-test

Can anyone tell me if the the multiple comparison of Kruskal Wallis test in R Agricolae package is a specific post hoc test? How does it work?

If it is a specific post hoc test, what is it? Could anyone recommend me literature?

Thank you!

Comment: Rather than start with whatever the software gives you, it is better to decide what test you want to use and then find the software to do that analysis for you...  As a post-hoc for Kruskal-Wallis, you might consider the Dunn test in the FSA package .

Answer (score -1):

They did give you a choice of tests there. You can specify the type of test you want under Did you have a look at the script?

```
kruskal(y, trt, alpha = 0.05, p.adj=c("none","holm","hommel",
        "hochberg", "bonferroni", "BH", "BY", "fdr"), group=TRUE, main = 
        NULL,console=FALSE)
```

Comment: The choices under `p.adj` aren't different tests. They are p-value adjustment methods to account for multiple tests.